# Некорректно работает поиск по проекту "Find in Path" в Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio

При попытке найти все вхождения строки в проекте в Андройд студии, всегда пользовался Find in Path (Ctrl+Shift+F). Всегда очень выручало, находило все.

Недавно заметил, что либо вообще не находит строки, либо не все вхождения строки в проекте. Даже может не найти только что выделенный фрагмент кода. Настройки, которые есть в окне поиска, все перепробовал.

Возможно как то связано с тем, что я установил по умолчанию английский интерфейс в Windows, и менял настройки форматов дат, чисел, либо это произошло с переходом на версию 3 Андройд студии, трудно сказать.

Создал Issue
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70997942
там есть скрины с подробностями.

Подскажите, как исправить работу поиска?

Comment: *Есть у кого нибудь подобные проблемы?* — это «вопрос-опросник». такие «вопросы» здесь не подходят. сформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос так, чтобы это был именно вопрос, на который вам смогут (или не смогут) дать объективный ответ. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кликните здесь  `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart..`   Кнопка `Invalidate and Restart`.
После перезагрузки попробуйте поискать снова.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, теперь все работает как надо.