# При использовании imageView и загрузки изображения появляется Render problem

Tags: java, android-studio

Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/picture. 
Добавление imageview через xml и java.
Приложение компилируется но когда открываешь акттвити с рисунком выдает ошибку и закрывается.
При api выше 24 все работает.

Comment: Попробуйте [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/764097/190461) решить

Comment: Ошибка рендеринга решилась , спасибо! Но картинка серая